# Google Assistant equivalent of Alexa tell [skill] to

Tags: actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, google-home, invocation

With Amazon Alexa it is possible to invoke an intent from a skill in 2 ways:

1. "Alexa start [skill name]."
   And then proceed to ask that skill for a specific intent.
2. "Alexa tell [skill name] to [specific intent]."

With Google Assistant I only know of calling an action by:

1. "Okay Google talk to [action name]."
   And then proceed to ask that action for a specific intent.

Is there an equivalent invocation to call specific intents from actions directly with the Google Assistant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do "Hey google, ask [action name] to [invocation phrase]" as part of an [explicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit#explicit_invocation_components). The documentation sometimes calls this a "deep link".

If you are using the Actions SDK, the Intent that matches the `invocation phrase` will be triggered.

If you are using Dialogflow, then you need to create an Intent that will match the `invocation phrase` and set it to be an additional welcome intent in the Invocations tab for the Action.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Thanks! It's hard to search for something when you don't know the term.